# Open new page using OnClientClick - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working in ASP.Net C#. Trying to invoke Downlaod.aspx page to download a file when a button (added in a gridview) is clicked. Following is code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View" UseSubmitBehavior="False"
    OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("window.open(""../../Views/Common/Download.aspx?PropertyDocumentID={0}""); return false;", Eval("DocumentId").ToString())%>' />
```

When i click it, i can see following error in browser console.

> **Uncaught SyntaxError:** Unexpected token `.`

But I am unable to figure out syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make a separate js function and use it like below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick='OpenWindow(<%# Eval("DocumentId").ToString() %>)' />
```

**JS function:**

```
function OpenWindow(documentId)
{
    window.open("../../Views/Common/Download.aspx?PropertyDocumentID=" + documentId); 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:

Method 1:

Change  double quote to single quote

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick = '<%#String.Format("window.open('../../Views/Common/Download.aspx?PropertyDocumentID={0}'); return false;');",Eval("DocumentId").ToString()) %>' />
```

Or remove your `string.Format` and use like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick = '<%#" window.open('../../Views/Common/Download.aspx?PropertyDocumentID=" + Eval("DocumentId").ToString() + "); return false;" %>' />
```

Method 2:

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClientClick='<%# "LocateMyPage(" + Eval("DocumentId").ToString() + ");" %>' />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function LocateMyPage(DocID){
     window.open('../../Views/Common/Download.aspx?PropertyDocumentID=' + DocID);
     return false;
 }

</script>
```